# Is it better to create a completely separate AWS account or just create a separate IAM user to have a separate development environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, cloud, amazon-ses

Currently, I am using these services in AWS:

1. EC2 instance
2. S3 bucket
3. SES for transactional mails

I access S3 and SES services in the backend using an `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, and an `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` which basically means I cannot share those keys with the developers.

I would like to create a **separate development environment** that doesn't give access to those **services in production**.

I have made some research and I found-out that I can [create a whole new account](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/separate-aws-production-and-development-accounts) for development environment and then synchronize billing between the two especially that I have AWS credits.

Before investing time in that, I wonder if it's possible to achieve my goal with using a separate **IAM identity**.

Comment: Yes, it is possible just with IAM but a separate account is better because you remove the risk of messing up your IAM permissions AND some configurations within the account affect the whole account and you *need* two accounts if you want to test those things.

Comment: luk here is your guy @AG_HIHI :D. Block boxing AWS accounts is easier with the help of AWS Control Tower and Organization. If you have so many teams and developers working in AWS, it will be the right options. If you have small project and less developers. IAM segregation will work for now.

Comment: Thank you all so much :D